# How to pause all youtube vidoes in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,I have "youtube video slider" and right now i am trying to stop all videos on button click,how can i do this ? here is my current code

```
return (
    <>
    <div className={`carousel-item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
        <YouTube videoId={post.VideoId} 
                                opts={opts} id="videosss"/>
        </div>
    </>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, If you want to stop all youtube videos, you can do with this DOM, as you can see the below code.

```
<div className={`carousel-item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
   <YouTube videoId={post.VideoId} opts={opts} id="videosss"/>
</div>
<button onClick={stopVideos}>Stop</button>

const stopVideos = () => {
   // do the videos loop for stopping all the videos
   videos.forEach(ele => {
      // getting all videos element for stopping the videos
      const element = document.getElementById(`${ele.VideoId}`);
      if (element) {
         element.pause();
      }
   })
}
```